# Describe Kafka Consumer Groups Response

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka 0.10.2.0 cluster and I'm using the Apache Kafka command line tools to debug why a particular Consumer Group is not receiving messages.

Using the `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_brokers> --list` I get a response that includes the Consumer Group ID I'm trying to debug.

Next, I use `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_brokers> --describe –group <consumer_group_id>` to retrieve details about topics, consumers, and offsets in relation to my misbehaving Consumer Group. I see a response I don't understand:

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                                      CLIENT-ID
-                              -          -               -               -          external-ems-link-status-f3ecd2cb-ab84-4043-b4f5-aa0c7d7d6bf0/10.100.0.18                 external-ems-link-status
-                              -          -               -               -          external-controller-topo-notification-b87e5e28-3cd2-48cf-ac6b-ed9a04b3881c/10.100.0.18    external-controller-topo-notification
-                              -          -               -               -          external-interface-status-alrm-c0190022-d359-4cd6-a872-8c50852f4c53/10.100.0.18            external-interface-status-alrm
-                              -          -               -               -          external-ctlr-link-status-5b34eefa-6a06-45cd-ad13-b78fa6c499a7/10.100.0.18                 external-ctlr-link-status
-                              -          -               -               -          external-flow-ctrl-status-2712c302-d7de-4d50-8dc8-473c05205b4b/10.100.0.18                 external-flow-ctrl-status
-                              -          -               -               -          external-ctrl-status-e9a9d77a-6dc5-445d-9e38-0d9c5c3a4af4/10.100.0.18                       external-ctrl-status
-                              -          -               -               -          external-bw-util-notification-4f746863-0c10-4d4c-8785-93401e904777/10.100.0.18             external-bw-util-notification
link-status                    0          2602            2602            0          -                                                 -                              -
```

What does it mean when I see no topic, or partition information for a particular consumer/host, client ID?

I can confirm that messages are being produced on those topics when I create a console consumer using the --zookeeper flag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tells you that there are a number of consumers in the group with no partitions assigned to them. If your `link-status` topic has only one partition, and the other consumers are subscribed to the same topic, this is the expected result (simply because each partition in the group can be consumed by one and only one consumer).

Comment: that's very helpful. The topics I'm trying to consumer by Consumers in  Group only have one partition.

Comment: wouldn't the describe consumer groups request show ALL consumers  under that group ID and what topics they're listening to? I thought Kafka  allows consumers from different groups to consume messages from the same topic.

Comment: Yes, it should show all consumers in the group and the topic/partitions assigned to them. Are your other consumers subscribed to other topics?

Comment: Your other statement is correct. Kafka allows consumers from different groups to consumer from the same topic partition. But they wouldn't be listed under the `--describe` command above since the command lists for one group only (through `--group` option).

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But from your answer above, It sounds like there is a collision between consumers of the same group accessing the same (one partition) topic.

Comment: That's correct. Even if consumers in a group are subscribed to the same one-partition topic, only one of them gets to consume from it. If these consumers need to consume from the topic at the same time they need to belong to different groups. I hope I did not misunderstand your point.